# Finding the name of the fractional part of a currency

Tags: java, icu

For Euro it is cents and for Indian Rupee it is Paisa. Is there a way to get the name of the fractional part **in java**. I have used `java.util.Currency.getDisplayName()` to get the name of the integer part of the currency. So far I have converted `2500.36` to `Euro two thousand five hundred and thirty-six`. But I want this to be converted to `Euro two thousand five hundred and thirty-six` **cents**.

I've used `icu4j` for conversion.

Comment: I have the same question!